# Asserting a Json Object

Tags: json, selenium, assert, assertion

I have an application where in there is a form which has all the controls like ( text box, dropdowns, list, text areas, checkbox, tables)
And all the data when it is saved it is saved as a json object and that object is stored in one of the column in the database.
Now I am automating this form and i would like to assert this page.

Approach taken so far :

From the UI page, captured all the data in a Dictionary object and then converted the same in the json object .
This is what it looks like

```
{
"AtRiskSchoolName": "11!!!!@@@@@@@@@@@@@",
"PercentFreeReduced": "11.00",
"IsAtRiskSite": "Yes",
"Associated": "Non-Profit Center or Public Institution: Children or Adults",
"FacilityType": "Rented/Leased",
"SiteTypes": "Child",
"ParticipantXIXX": "1",
"ParticipantFree": "8",
"ParticipantReduced": "8",
"ParticipantPaid": "99",
"TraditionalMeals[0].Value1": "6:00am",
"TraditionalMeals[0].Value2": "6:30am",
"TraditionalMeals[0].Value3": "7:00am",
"TraditionalMeals[0].Value4": "7:30am",
"TraditionalMeals[1].Value1": "8:00am",
"TraditionalMeals[1].Value2": "8:30am",
"TraditionalMeals[1].Value3": "9:00am",
"TraditionalMeals[1].Value4": "9:30am",
"TraditionalMeals[2].Value1": "11:00am",
"TraditionalMeals[2].Value2": "11:30am",
"TraditionalMeals[2].Value3": "12:00pm",
"TraditionalMeals[2].Value4": "12:30pm"
```

}

And from the database captured the entire json object and then parsed it as json object.
Json object from the database looks like :-

```
{
"AlwaysOptional": false,
"Associated": "Non-Profit",
"AtRiskAreaEligibilityExpiryDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"AtRiskMeals": [{
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Breakfast",
        "Value1": "7:00am",
        "Value2": "7:30am",
        "Value3": null,
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Morning Snack",
        "Value1": null,
        "Value2": null,
        "Value3": null,
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Lunch",
        "Value1": null,
        "Value2": null,
        "Value3": null,
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Afternoon Snack",
        "Value1": null,
        "Value2": null,
        "Value3": null,
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Supper",
        "Value1": null,
        "Value2": null,
        "Value3": null,
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Evening Snack",
        "Value1": null,
        "Value2": null,
        "Value3": null,
        "Value4": null
    }
],
"AtRiskSchoolName": "11!!!!@@@@@@@@@@@@@",
"Ethnic": [{
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Hispanic or Latino (Cuban, Mexican, Puerto Rican, South or Central American, or other Spanish culture or origin regardless of race.)",
        "Value1": "1",
        "Value2": "50.00",
        "Value3": "50",
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Non-Hispanic or Non-Latino (All others, Irish, French, German, etc.)",
        "Value1": "1",
        "Value2": "50.00",
        "Value3": "50",
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Total",
        "Value1": "2",
        "Value2": "100.00",
        "Value3": "100.00",
        "Value4": null
    }
],
"FacilityType": "sitelease",
"IsAtRiskSite": true,
"ParticipantFree": 8,
"ParticipantPaid": 99,
"ParticipantReduced": 8,
"ParticipantXIXX": 1,
"PercentFreeReduced": 11.0,
"Racial": [{
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "White",
        "Value1": "1",
        "Value2": "14.29",
        "Value3": "10",
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Black or African American",
        "Value1": "1",
        "Value2": "14.29",
        "Value3": "10",
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "American Indian or Alaskan Native",
        "Value1": "1",
        "Value2": "14.29",
        "Value3": "10",
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Asian",
        "Value1": "1",
        "Value2": "14.29",
        "Value3": "10",
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Native Hawaiian",
        "Value1": "1",
        "Value2": "14.29",
        "Value3": "40",
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Some Other Race",
        "Value1": "1",
        "Value2": "14.29",
        "Value3": "10",
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Two or More Races",
        "Value1": "1",
        "Value2": "14.29",
        "Value3": "10",
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Total",
        "Value1": "7",
        "Value2": "100.00",
        "Value3": "100.00",
        "Value4": null
    }
],
"SiteIsRemoved": false,
"SiteName": "Beaver",
"SiteType": "Child",
"TotalEnrolled": 115,
"TraditionalMeals": [{
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Breakfast",
        "Value1": "6:00am",
        "Value2": "6:30am",
        "Value3": "7:00am",
        "Value4": "7:30am"
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Morning Snack",
        "Value1": "8:00am",
        "Value2": "8:30am",
        "Value3": "9:00am",
        "Value4": "9:30am"
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Lunch",
        "Value1": "11:00am",
        "Value2": "11:30am",
        "Value3": "12:00pm",
        "Value4": "12:30pm"
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Afternoon Snack",
        "Value1": null,
        "Value2": null,
        "Value3": null,
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Supper",
        "Value1": null,
        "Value2": null,
        "Value3": null,
        "Value4": null
    }, {
        "Address": null,
        "Type": "Evening Snack",
        "Value1": null,
        "Value2": null,
        "Value3": null,
        "Value4": null
    }
]
```

}

Problem comes when I am trying to assert both the objects, it is failing as the object from the database is having few elements as array meaning you can have multiple objects in the single json object.
And when I am trying to construct my Json object from the UI elements, I am not able to construct the array of elements.

Please advice if this is right approach to do the same.

I am using selenium with C#

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by creating a Dictionary object from the UI and then converting the json object in Dictionary object.